# Does the sequence of mean values converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am to disprove or show the following statement. Depending on whether it is correct. Can anyone give me some hints?

Let $(x_k){k\geq 1} \in S(\mathbb{R})$ converges. Then $\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k\right)_{n\geq 1}$ converges.

Comment: This is a specific case of [Cesàro summation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation).

Comment: What's $S(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: The set of all sequences in R

Comment: @Lachkus $S(\Bbb{R})$ is some highly non standard notation for the set of real sequences. Usually one writes $\Bbb{R}^{\Bbb{N}}$ or just directly writes "the space of real sequences"

Comment: I know but I’m just doing what my prof tells me to do

Answer (score 1):

This is what is called Cauchy's First Limit Theorem in some books.  See that if $x_{n}\to a  $  then for each $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N_{1}$ such that $|x_{n}-a|\leq \epsilon\,,\forall \,n\geq N_{1}$ . Then for $M>N_{1}$ you have $$|\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{M}x_{k}}{M}-a|=|\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{N_{1}-1}x_{k}}{M}+\frac{\sum_{k=N_{1}}^{M}x_{k}}{M}-a|$$

$$=|\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{N_{1}-1}(x_{k}-a)}{M}+\frac{\sum_{k=N_{1}}^{M}(x_{k}-a)}{M}|$$

Now pick $M_{1}>N_{1}$ such that $\frac{1}{m}\sum_{k=1}^{N_{1}-1}|x_{k}-a|<\epsilon$ for all $m\geq M_{1}$ . Notice that $M_{1}$ depends on $N_{1}$ and $\epsilon$ and hence only on $\epsilon$ as $N_{1}$ depends only on $\epsilon$ .

Now $|x_{k}-a|\leq \epsilon \,,\forall n\geq N_{1}$ . Hence $\sum_{k=N_{1}}^{M}\frac{|x_{k}-a|}{M}\leq \frac{\epsilon (M-N_{1}+1)}{M}\leq \epsilon$

Thus for all $M\geq M_{1}$ you have $|\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{M}x_{k}}{M}-a|\leq \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{N_{1}-1}|x_{k}-a|}{M}+\frac{\sum_{k=N_{1}}^{M}|x_{k}-a|}{M}\leq \epsilon+\epsilon$

Hence you have the required convergence

Comment: Right. This is the usual initial bad part-final good part argument which occurs often. The good part is where things behave well and the bad part is where anything can happen. When the good part gets sufficiently large compared to the bad part, the bad part becomes relatively insignificant so only the good part matters.

Comment: @martycohen I don't know why but when I was reading your comment , it felt like Morgan Freeman was narrating it.

Comment: All I can say to that is thank you.